# Markov chains and conditional probability on subset of state space

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the Markov chain $(X_n)$ consisting of the three states $\{1,2,3\}$ and having transition probability matrix
$$\left (\begin{matrix} 1/3 & 2/3 & 0\\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ).$$
The distribution of $X_0$ is $(0.1;0.3;0.6)$. Find
$$Pr(X_1 \in \{1,2\}|X_0 \in \{1,3\}).$$

Comment: Since this is essentially a matter of definition checking, it would help to mention what is stopping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(X_1\in\{1,2\} |X_0\in \{1,3\}) = \frac{P(X_1\in\{1,2\}, X_0\in \{1,3\})}{P(X_0 \in \{1,3\})} = \frac{P(X_1\in\{1,2\}|X_0 = 1)P(X_0=1) + P(X_1\in\{1,2\}| X_0=3)P(X_0=3)}{P(X_0 = 1) + P(X_0=3)} = \dotsi
$$
Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @McGreen. But how can I continue to compute $P(X_1 \in \{1,2\},X_0=1)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made a careless mistake... Corrected it!

Comment: Ok. That's true now. But how to evaluate the new one?

Comment: $P(X_1\in\{1,2\}|X_0=1) = P(X_1=1|X_0=1)+P(X_1=2|X_0=1)$, here everything is given.

Comment: @McGreen. Thank a lot!